# Repeating digits in the Pythagorean triad

Tags: python

I have written a fun that counts pitagorian triad:

```
def triad(N):
    for a in range(1,N):
        for b in range(1,N):
            for c in range(1,N):
                if a*a+b*b==c*c and a!=b and b!=a:
                    print(a,b,c)
                    print('-'*10)
triad(20)
```

but the output is:

```
3 4 5
----------
4 3 5
----------
5 12 13
----------
6 8 10
----------
8 6 10
----------
8 15 17
----------
9 12 15
----------
12 5 13
----------
12 9 15
----------
15 8 17
----------
```

and I don't want:

```
3 4 5
----------
4 3 5
---------
```

and

```
6 8 10
----------
8 6 10
----------
```

How to get rid of repeating digits?

I tried a!=b and b!=a

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to start `b` as `a + 1` and `c` as `a + 2`:

```
def triad(N):
    for a in range(1, N):
        for b in range(a + 1, N):
            for c in range(a + 2, N):
                if a * a + b * b == c * c:
                    print(a, b, c)
                    print('-' * 10)

triad(20)
```

**Output**

```
3 4 5
----------
5 12 13
----------
6 8 10
----------
8 15 17
----------
9 12 15
----------
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ["tree of primitive Pythagorian triples"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples):

```
def pythagorianTriples(n):
    def mul(m, a):  # Multiplication of matrix with vector
        return [sum(x * y for x, y in zip(row, a)) for row in m]
                
    matrices = (
        (
            (1, -2, 2),
            (2, -1, 2),
            (2, -2, 3)
        ), (
            (1, 2, 2),
            (2, 1, 2),
            (2, 2, 3)
        ), (
            (-1, 2, 2),
            (-2, 1, 2),
            (-2, 2, 3)
        )
    )
    q = [[3, 4, 5]]
    while q:
        a = q.pop()
        b = sorted(a)
        if b[-1] <= n:
            # yield this triple and multiples of it
            while b[-1] <= n:
                yield b
                for i in range(3):
                    b[i] += a[i]
            # add 3 more triples to the list
            q.extend(mul(m, a) for m in matrices)

for res in pythagorianTriples(20):
    print(res)
```

This outputs:

```
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 8, 10]
[9, 12, 15]
[12, 16, 20]
[8, 15, 17]
[5, 12, 13]
```

Comment: This is much more scalable! (to high N)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without the 3rd loop and much efficient

```py
import math

def triad(N):
    for a in range(1, N):
        for b in range(a + 1, N):
            sq = a * a + b * b
            c = int(math.sqrt(sq))
            if sq == c * c and c > b:
                print(a, b, c)
                print('-' * 10)

triad(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be:

```
def triad(N):
    for a in range(1,N):
        for b in range(1,N):
            for c in range(1,N):
                if (a*a + b*b) == c*c and a < b:
                    print(a,b,c)
                    print(10*"-")

triad(20)
```

Output:

```
3 4 5
----------
5 12 13
----------
6 8 10
----------
8 15 17
----------
9 12 15
----------
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using itertools

One thing about [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is it returns the items in the same order as the iterable so it's safe to assume that the 3rd item is the only possible hypotenuse.

```
from itertools import combinations
from math import sqrt

def triad(N):
    return [c for c in combinations(range(1, N), 3) 
            if sqrt(c[0]**2 + c[1]**2) == c[2]]
        
print(triad(20))
```

Output:

```
[(3, 4, 5), (5, 12, 13), (6, 8, 10), (8, 15, 17), (9, 12, 15)]
```